# In a RESTful web service, what HTTP method should an increment functionality use?

Tags: rest, http

As an example:

I have a RESTful web service. It has a `GET /status/:item_id` endpoint.

I want to allow the progression of the item to the next status, but I do not want to allow for the specification of a status: 
`{SOME-HTTP-METHOD} /status/:item_id/next`.

What HTTP method should I use? Is the approach listed above RESTful?

Comment: no, i dont thinks the aproach is RESTful, 'status' is probably a property of an item, not a resource itself

Comment: @JohnnyAW in this service the item as a whole would never be exposed to the client. So there is not a `/item`.

Comment: in a RESTful way you would normally have an item-resource `/items/:itemId` and you would update it's status by a PUT-Request on the resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem like a `POST` request would be [the most semantic](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5):

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources;
> - (others...)

Comment: Since the entity is not enclosed in the request would it still be a POST? Since the status is being changed could it be considered a PUT?

Comment: @Nelson I thought about that, too, but `PUT` expects a payload: _The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI_ (from same link, RFC) so I'd say no.